# Set function value inside a stored procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I need set a function value inside a stored procedure.

I have this procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spTeste]
AS           
    SET NOCOUNT ON;      

    DECLARE @cvT int    

    SET @cvT = (SELECT dbo.funcTem())

    SELECT @cvT

GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[funcTem]()    
RETURNS INT
BEGIN       
    DECLARE @vvTempoPr int

    SET @vvTempoPr = 5

    RETURN  @vvTempoPr  

END

GO

exec spTeste
```

The `funcTem` return number 5 but inside a proc the function is return 0

Comment: That is not a valid stored procedure. Show more code and how you are checking the value.

Comment: Sorry @MartinSmith but I can't work's rules! :(

Comment: @MartinSmith I need know how I can get the function value, only this, my Proc is ok

Comment: Can you show a cut down toy example that reproduces the issue then? Your question is impossible to answer without resorting to guessing otherwise.

Comment: `EXEC spTeste` returns a scalar resultset with the value `5` when I run that?

Comment: It works fine for me: `select dbo.funcTem()` and `exec spTeste` return `5`.

Comment: @soamazing - which SQL product are you using? In Microsoft SQL Server 2005 this code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the stored procedure with `EXEC` to capture the return value.

Instead of this:

```
SET @cvT = (SELECT dbo.funcTem())
```

...you need to do this:

```
EXEC @cvT = dbo.funcTem()
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the original works in SQL Server 2005, try changing

```
SET @cvT = (SELECT dbo.funcTem())
```

to

```
SELECT @cvT = dbo.funcTem();
```

Using EXEC instead of SELECT does not work in SQL Server 2005, fyi. Results in error "Incorrect syntax near ')'." when trying to create the stored proc.